# ie gives "...is null or not an object" errors when accessing an object?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've got a JavaScript object literal:

```
var things = {
    "a": {
        7: {
            "b": "asdf",
            "z": {
                1: {
                    "name": "Ship0",
                    "loa": 100,
                    "draft": 5000
                },
                2: {
                    "name": "Ship1",
                    "loa": 100,
                    "draft": 5000
                }
            }
        },
        8: {
            "b": "fdsa",
            "z": {
                5: {
                    "name": "Ship0",
                    "loa": 100,
                    "draft": 5000
                },
                6: {
                    "name": "Ship1",
                    "loa": 100,
                    "draft": 5000
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

... and later in a function, I do this:

```
function p_get_index_of_existing_ship(customer_id, ship_id)
{
    return someotherfunctionof(ship_id, things["a"][customer_id]["z"]);
}
```

It works nicely in firefox, but in IE(7,8) I get "error: 'things.a[...].z' is null or not an object.

Is that not the right way to access such associative arrays (objects) in javascript?

Comment: What's the value of `customer_id`?

Comment: I'm not javascirpt expert, but shouldn't your syntax be things.a[customer_id].z?

Comment: @Babak Naffas: `x["a"]` is the same as `x.a` for all a such that a is a valid identifier. The former form can accept non-valid identifiers. `x["Hello world"]`

Comment: @Colin Because of the lack of troubleshooting -- I have trivially answered the question below. There are two alternatives. I would recommend installing the IE Script Debugger and/or using the IE8 Developer Tools to diagnosis your problem better.

Comment: Learn something new everyday, thanks @pst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `...[customer_id]` evaluates to undefined.

Now, figure out why.

Comment: @Šime Vidas That assumes that other browsers pass in the same value of `customer_id`. The other alternative is that the `things` in question is not as expected. In both cases it doesn't change the above statement (which I derived from looking at the error message -- IE lays it out in a particular format).

Comment: Yeah both browsers have the same value for customer_id. I think the answer is that IE doesn't like literal numbers for keys...

Comment: @Colin Well, you used the IE Debugger (IE8 "Developer Tools") and inspected the value of `things` and saw what? You looked for parse errors (or error suppressors) and saw what?

Comment: @Colin IE seems to like the code posted just fine. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgyhn/PnLyw/)

Comment: @Colin: no, that's not the answer.  All keys are strings on object literals - even if you define it as a number it is coerced to a string.  The same goes for when you access the property - if you use a number or any other value, that value is coerced to a string before the property is accessed.  IE behaves no differently from any other browser in that respect.  I think it's more likely that pst is right and your problem isn't related to the snippets of code in your question.

Comment: @Andy - I'm inclined to agree, will know more in a bit. I think it's a different difference between IE and FF that's throwing me...

Comment: @pst, everyone: Fine, you were right. It does evaluate to undefined. This is what threw me (and maybe I'm mistaken about this as well, but I hope not): that function gets called in on_load() (called from <body onload="on_load">. IE complains. FF doesn't - it fails silently. After it calls that function, it doesn't continue the on_load(), but it doesn't complain either. So that was a red herring. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 2):

The keys of object literals must be valid identifier names. Your keys are `7` and `8` which are not valid names (because the first (and only) character is a digit). I suggest using strings instead:

```
"7": { ... }
```

**Edit:** I looked up the spec... It seems that numeric literals are valid names for keys... but it still could be that IE doesn't like them. Try strings and you'll know.

**Edit:** Try this:

```
function p_get_index_of_existing_ship(customer_id, ship_id)
{
    // return someotherfunctionof(ship_id, things["a"][customer_id]["z"]);
    things["a"][customer_id]["z"];
}
```

Does the error still show in IE?

Comment: So, I would conclude that IE does NOT accept numeric literals for keys, I guess. So it's an IE feature...

Comment: @Colin Well, does it work in IE when you use strings instead?

Comment: It still is not valid JSON without quotes on the key names. I would expect a *parse error* from IE if it rejected the syntax.

Comment: @pst JSON-compliance would be another issue. According to the spec (ES5), property names (keys) may be numeric literals.

Comment: @pst that's assuming the OP is using `JSON.parse` and not `eval`, *or* that he isn't confused about the difference between an object literal and a JSON string.

Comment: @Andy The OP's code is an object literal. He probably just used the wrong term to refer to it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the `var` declaration when I skim-read.  Still, IE has no problem trying to access string properties using numbers.  The number will be coerced using `toString()`, so providing the keys match after the coercion (and the OP hasn't done anything crazy with `Number.prototype.toString()`), this won't be an issue.

Comment: @Andy I believe that, when coercing, JavaScript uses the internal coercion methods (defined in chapter 9, for instance `ToString()`) and not the "public" ones. ... so that won't be an issue.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: you're right in the case of primitives, but for Objects (including Number objects) the `toString()` method is called.  The spec is a little hazy on this so I tested it in a few browsers to verify it.